# VBScript to move file with wildcard, if it exists

Tags: vbscript, wildcard, file-exists

I am attempting to create a script that checks for the existence of archived eventlog files and, if any files exist, moves them to another folder. Running this script does nothing and gives no errors. I believe the wildcard in the If statement is what is giving me issues. I am new to vbscript, and scripting in general, and would appreciate some advice.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If (fso.FileExists("d:\eventlogs\Archive*.evtx")) Then
    FSO.CopyFile "d:\eventlogs\Archive*.evtx" , "d:\eventlogs\archive\"
    FSO.Deletefile "d:\eventlogs\archive*.evtx"
End if
```

Comment: Why `VBScript` when `DOS` batch files can do the above simplier?

Answer (score 4):

You can replicate a wild card search by using a combination of `instr()` and `right()`, or just multiple `instr()`.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "d:\eventlogs\"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
   if instr(objFile.Name,"Archive") <> 0 AND instr(objFile.Name,".evtx") <> 0 then
       objFSO.MoveFile objFile.Name, "archive\" + objFile.Name
   end if
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate approach of finding files with wildcards in VBScript:

1. Get the file collection from the containing folder
2. For each file in the filecollection:
3. Test the filename with a regular expression on a certain pattern
4. If the test passes, do some action with this file
5. Next file

Comment: In this case I'd string comparisons for extension and the beginning of the filename might be easier to handle than a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but might be useful because apparently nobody spotted the mistake.

From the VBScript documentation (`script56.chm` in my case), help page for `CopyFile` method says:

> **FileExists Method**
>
> Returns **True** if a specified file exists; **False** if it does
>   not.
>
> `object.FileExists(filespec)`
>
> **Arguments**
>
> *object*
>
> Required. Always the name of a **FileSystemObject**.
>
> *filespec*
>
> Required. The name of the file whose existence is to be determined. A complete path specification (either absolute or relative) must be provided if the file isn't expected to exist in the current folder.

Hence your expression `fso.FileExists("d:\eventlogs\Archive*.evtx")` returns **False** here; indeed there isn't any file named `Archive*.evtx` in your folder.

Either you remove your test, but you'll have to deal with the error the `CopyFile` method  might generate, as doc says:

> An error also occurs if a source using wildcard characters doesn't match any files.

As suggested by @automatedchaos in his answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20907209/666414 you can also loop through files of the folder and decide what to do whenever the filename/extension matches your pattern.

Lastly, you can mix both solutions: loop through files of the folder, then set a flag to **True** and `Exit Loop` as soon as you encounter an expected file, then use the `CopyFile` method.

Like this:

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For Each objFile in .GetFolder("d:\eventlogs\").Files
        If Left(objFile.Name, 7) = "Archive" And .GetExtensionName(objFile) = "evtx" Then
            archiveFound = True
        End If
    Next

    If archiveFound Then
        .CopyFile "d:\eventlogs\Archive*.evtx", "d:\eventlogs\archive\"
        .DeleteFile "d:\eventlogs\Archive*.evtx"
    End If
End With
```

Note the wildcards work with the `DeleteFile` method too!